CakePHP 5 get body data of POST request
I am creating a REST API using CakePHP 5. I have a POST function that should receive the data from postman and input it to the database. The problem is I am not receiving the data in the request. The GET request is working well so this is definitely not a database issue. The received data is being shown as an empty array [] with 200 as a response code. Thank you for your time.
routes.php
$routes->scope('/api', function (RouteBuilder $builder): void {
    $builder->connect('/product/insert', ['controller' => 'Product', 'action' => 'insertProduct'])->setMethods(['POST']);
});

ProductController.php
public function insertProduct() 
{
    $product = $this -> Product -> newEmptyEntity();
    $product = $this -> Product -> patchEntity($product, $this -> request -> getData());
    $this -> Product -> save($product);
}

Other things I have tried from the framework's documentation:
$product_name = $this -> request -> getData('product_name');
$product = $this -> Product -> newEntity([
        'name' => $product_name,
]);

$content = json_encode(['method' => __METHOD__, 'class' => get_called_class()]); 
$data = $this->request->getParsedBody(); 
$product = $this -> Product -> newEntity($this->request->getData()); 
debug($this->request);
I also have Table and Entity classes:
ProductTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ProductTable extends Table
{
      public function initialize(array $config): void
      {
           $this -> setTable('product');
           parent::initialize($config);
      }
}

Product.php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Product extends Entity
{

}

Postman Snippet


You need to send the request with header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. In Postman, change radio selection from 'form-data' to 'x-www-form-url-encoded' and debug the request: debug($this->request->getData());

The answer by wappy is the correct answer
You need to send the request with header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. In Postman, change radio selection from 'form-data' to 'x-www-form-url-encoded' and debug the request: debug($this->request->getData());

Change radio selection from 'form-data' to 'x-www-form-url-encoded' in Postman and you should have data in $_POST:
public function insertProduct()
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post']);

    $associations = [];
    $product = $this->Product->newEmptyEntity();
    // $this->Authorization->authorize($product); // Optional, if you use Authorization

    $data = $this->Product->sanitizeData($this->request->getData(), 'add', $this->authAdmin);
    $product = $this->Product->patchEntity($product, $data, ['associated' => $associations]);

    if ($this->Product->save($product)) {
        $this->set([
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => __('The product has been saved.'),
            'data' => $product,
        ]);
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', ['status', 'message', 'data']);
        return null;
    }

    $this->set([
        'status' => 400,
        'message' => __('The product could not be saved. Please try again.'),
        'errors' => $product->getErrors(),
    ]);
    $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', ['status', 'message', 'errors']);
    $this->setResponse($this->response->withStatus(400));
    return null;
}

